# triggerIO upload image from gallery

Tags: trigger.io

I am unable to upload an image via trigger through gallery using coffeescript

relevant code:

Main script:

```
CameraHelper.fileUpload (file) =>
    @file = file
    forge.file.URL file, (url) =>
        @fileURL = url
        @$("#uploadImg").addClass("fadeIn").css("background-image", "url(#{url})")
    , (content) ->
        error "Error finding Image"
    , ->
        debug "Upload Cancelled"
```

Camera Helper:

```
fileUpload: (success, err) ->
    forge.file.getImage
        saveLocation: "file"
    , (file) ->
            debug "Successfully uploaded img"
            success?(file)
    , (content) ->
            error "Error in uploading img", content
            err?()
```

relevant debug info:

When camera is selected and taken:

```
[FORGE] '{"uri":"/var/mobile/Applications/1BC9C0D7-5830-402E-913A-C39764B41F26/Library/Application Support/Forge/389301995108.jpg","name":"Image","type":"image"}'
all.js:2[FORGE] 'Successfully uploaded img'
```

When Gallery image is chosen:

```
assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=A3907A31-A8F9-4763-AEF2-67BA84F8E245&ext=JPG 
Failed to load resource: unsupported URL
```

Comment: Can you share some more of your code; in particular, the bit that's doing the upload?

Comment: added more, see above

Comment: Ah, so you're not actually uploading the image? The problem occurs when you capture it? Can you include the full logs (with debug output enabled)?

Comment: @JamesBrady not at this point; however, it seems to be fully working now. I think the issue may have been cause by originally not having the: forge.file.URL function. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved.

had to add the forge.file.URL function to be able to properly access the URL of the image

[more details here](https://trigger.io/docs/current/api/modules/file.html#forgefileurlfile-success-error)